# Signed URL Laravel retorna vista vacía

Tags: laravel, url

Estoy implementando signed url en mi proyecto laravel, cree la ruta que quiero vaya firmada para evitar que algún usuario cambie los parámetros.  La versión de laravel que estoy usando tiene ésta funcionalidad ya integrada, por lo que me queda es modificada el route/web

```
De:Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'/encuestas/{encuesta}/aplicar', 'EncuestasController@aplicar_encuesta');

A:  #Signed URL
   Route::get('/encuestas/{encuesta}/aplicar', function ($encuesta) {
    // Petición a aplicar encuesta.
    })->name('encuestas.aplicar_encuesta')->middleware('signed');
```

Y en el link donde quiero se firme la url:

```
    <a href="{{ url()->signedRoute('encuestas.aplicar_encuesta', ['id_encuesta' => $object->id_encuesta]) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Aplicar</a>
```

Pero al ejecutar no me da ningún error, simplemente me devuelve una vista vacia. Una página en blanco...

alguien tiene idea de cómo integrar correctamente las signed url? qué me falta por configurar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu versión de laravel es superior a 5.6.11,  solo veo un pequeño error: Tu declaras la ruta:

```
Route::get('/encuestas/{encuesta}/aplicar', function ($encuesta) {
    // Petición a aplicar encuesta.
})->name('encuestas.aplicar_encuesta')->middleware('signed');
```

Y la Variable dinámica que se tiene es solo una: `encuesta` pero al momento de llamar a la ruta:

```
url()->signedRoute('encuestas.aplicar_encuesta', ['id_encuesta' => $object->id_encuesta])
```

Tu utilizas `id_encuesta` en cambio deberías de utilizar solo `encusta`.

Otra observación; no se si el **Helper url()** funcione de forma correcta con **signedRoute**, porque no tratas de cambiarlo por el **Facade: URL**, quedando tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
URL::signedRoute('encuestas.aplicar_encuesta', ['encuesta' => $object->id_encuesta])
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a hacer lo que me indicas

Comment: Efectivamente, la versión es Laravel Framework 5.6.28, hice todo lo que detallas pero sigue igual, la vista sigue siendo una página en blanco